# Factorial Simplification to a number

Tags: factorial

Can the following be simplified to a number?

$$\frac{2019 \times 2018 \times \cdots \times 1961}{59!}$$

This was asked in an probability statistics exam, i only could infer $2019!/(1960!59!)$.

Comment: Yes. It is $$3085813263641908562328160265790534882111622087372801050561976533594289729982354168121031348210010889610358224505880$$

Comment: Im not sure if theyd just want us to evaluate it? We're only given scientific calculators, no mathematica or R.

Comment: If this was an answer to a question it is sufficient to write $\binom{2019}{59}$

Comment: Yeah i think ur right on that one.

Comment: Wait, you mean, you haven't memorized the first 3,000 rows of Pascal's triangle?

Comment: Not only is it *sufficient* to write $\binom{2019}{59}$ leaving the expression unsimplified, it is often *preferable* to leave it unsimplified.  Seeing the unsimplified answers to counting and probability questions speaks volumes as to the thought process that went into the answer and can help to very quickly and easily verify its correctness.  I would avoid tedious calculations and evaluations wherever possible unless it was immediately obvious where a simplification can be done (*such as one that is a result of a well known theorem*).